# esp8266 & ws2812 lua script hangs after the http request

Tags: lua, esp8266

I have written a LUA script whereby the color of the ws2812 changes when I call a url.

It is so that the ESP hangs when you first call the URL (http://IPADDRESS/?color=green&key=rpi). The color will be switched, but after that depends the ESP.

I've tried a lot. I do not know how to solve my problem. Connected is the PixelRing (ws2812) to D4 (gpio2).

Do you have a solution idea?

```
local SSID = "*******"
local SSID_PASSWORD = "******"

LED_COUNT = 12
SECRET_KEY = "rpi"

local buffer = nil

--ws2812.init()

function wait_for_wifi_conn ( )
   tmr.alarm (1, 1000, 1, function ( )
      if wifi.sta.getip ( ) == nil then
         print ("Waiting for Wifi connection")
      else
         tmr.stop (1)
         print ("ESP8266 mode is: " .. wifi.getmode ( ))
         print ("The module MAC address is: " .. wifi.ap.getmac ( ))
         print ("Config done, IP is " .. wifi.sta.getip ( ))


        ws2812.init() 
        buffer = ws2812.newBuffer(LED_COUNT, 3)
      end
   end)
end

function connect(conn) 

print("c2", conn);
    conn:on ("receive",
    function (cn, req_data)
        if req_data:find('^GET /.* HTTP/1.1') ~= nil then
            local key = string.match(req_data, "key=(%a+)")
            local color = string.match(req_data, "color=(%a+)")

            if key == SECRET_KEY then

                local r, g, b = nil, nil, nil
                if color == "red" then
                    r = 255
                    g = 0
                    b = 0
                elseif color == "blue" then
                    r = 0
                    g = 0
                    b = 255
                elseif color == "green" then
                    r = 0
                    g = 255
                    b = 0
                end
                if r ~= nil then
                    tmr.alarm(2, 100, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function()
                        --buffer = ws2812.newBuffer(LED_COUNT, 3);
                        buffer:fill(g,r,b); -- grb not rgb
                        print(buffer)
                        --ws2812.init()
                        ws2812.write(nil, buffer)

                    end)
                end

            end            
        end

            -- Close the connection for the request
        cn:on("sent",function(c) print("c0", c);c:close() end)
        cn:send("<h1> Hello, NodeMcu.</h1>") 

        -- Close the connection for the request
        --cn:on("sent",function(cnn) cnn:close() end) 
    end)
    --conn:send("<h1> Hello, NodeMcu.</h1>")
end

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config {ssid=SSID, pwd=SSID_PASSWORD}
wifi.sta.autoconnect(1)

wait_for_wifi_conn()

svr = net.createServer(net.TCP, 30)

if svr then
    svr:listen (80, connect)
end
```

Thanks for Help =)

Comment: I would reduce everything in `function (cn, req_data)` to the bare minimum (e.g. dumping `requ_data` to console) and start from there. You can then statement by statement to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: For a small template you may want to take a look at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#example_6

Comment: When I uncomment the WS2812 part everything works. So it hangs due to the ws2812 lib.

Comment: When you run the WS2812 code in isolation all is well?

Comment: No, if I do it without the WS2812 code.